# Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object

Tags: java, android

Writing of this hashmap goes well but when i try to read it, it throws exception.

Data object is serializable and as I said, I have no problem writing it, only reading in.readSerializable();

I also checked all fields in Data and subfields and they are all serializable

```
12-12 14:21:11.070 10173-10173/E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{activities.CustomObjectsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = ۳)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5437)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = ۳)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2508)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2477)
        at models.custom_fields.CustomObject.<init>(CustomObject.java:136)
        at models.custom_fields.CustomObject$1.createFromParcel(CustomObject.java:145)
        at models.custom_fields.CustomObject$1.createFromParcel(CustomObject.java:142)

@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeSerializable(this.custom_fields);
    }

    protected CustomObject(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        this.customFields = (HashMap<String, Data>) 
        in.readSerializable();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the exception + stack trace ?

Comment: there you go @Benoit